# BASH: finding partition from diskutil output

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, maintenance

I'm trying to search the output of a command listing local drives to find a partition called EFI on the boot HDD.

I've written a really dirty oneliner as I can't seem to work out how to effectively find the main HDD (presumably always Macintosh HD) and then to find out what the EFI partition on the same drive, and then from there find the disk#s# IDENTIFIER for the EFI partition on the Macintosh HD drive.

The standard output from `diskutil list` is something like this

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            499.1 GB   disk0s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             784.2 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.5 TB     disk1
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
2:                  Apple_HFS Data                    1.5 TB     disk1s2
```

So here's the dirty one liner I've been using. Is there a better way I can do this?

`diskutil mount $(diskutil list | grep -i 'Macintosh\ HD' | awk '{print $6}' | grep -i 'disk0s')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume /dev/disk0 is always the "main" HDD, right? If not and you really want to find the EFI partition on the disk named "Macintosh HD" then your oneliner is almost correct.

For me $6 returns 'GB' and I'm also assuming the EFI partition is always the first of that particular disk, so try:

```
diskutil list | grep 'Macintosh HD' | awk '{print $(NF)}' | sed 's/s[0-9]/s1/'
```

or some more awk trickery (for good measure):

```
diskutil list | awk '/Macintosh HD/ { sub(/s[0-9]/, "s1", $(NF)); print $(NF) }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and detect the main block device by using:

`mount | awk '/on \/ / {print $1}'`

I can't seem to find a way to detect my main volume since my output doesn't list them, I can only see the main block device and some description of the content:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         250.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *249.8 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-7C6C089FXXXX
                                 Unencrypted
```

In my case I can easily use `awk '/Logical Volume/ {print $NF}'` but a more robust script will take the Mac version into account to check all possible cases.

BTW, I'm using Yosemite 10.10.4 on MBP 15" Mid 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is not complete, but I ran out of time.

So, I use the df command, because I know that this will have the mount point at the end. Then I grep it with a pattern of slash newline. And then I wanted to cut everything after the first space sign out. But the cutting out doesn't work right now. Don't really know what I am doing wrong and I have to start working for my job right now, but maybe you can improve the cutting out of the bash feature. Sorry, no time to look the manual up to find my mistake. But we're almost there:

Corrected:

```
foo=$(df -h | grep -e ' /$'); loo=${foo%%" "*}; echo $loo
```

Now it works. Try it :)

EDIT:
Oh, I just realised that I am using a lvg, therefore disk0s[0-4] will be translated to disk1. So, test it and tell me if this is correctly showing you the right disk you're not using an lvg.

EDIT 2:
Still not working for encrypted logic volume group, but if you could test this one without FileVault, it should work

```
foo=$(mount | grep -e ' / '); foo=${foo%%" "*}; diskutil list | grep "[0-99]:" | grep ${foo##"/dev/"} | grep EFI)
```

This would look for an EFI on the disk on which ist mounted as root, so usually MacintoshHD

EDIT 3:
This is really great to kill time at work. Okay, I guess this should give you the right answer. It can do so even if it is FileVault encrypted.

```
#!/bin/bash

maindrive=$(mount | grep -e " / ")
maindrive_exact=${maindrive%%" "*}
maindrive_reduced=${maindrive_exact##"/dev/"}

if [ "$(diskutil list | grep Unlocked)" = "" ]
        then
                diskline=$(diskutil list | grep "[0-99]:" | grep $maindrive_reduced | grep EFI)
                diskline_cut1=${diskline##*"B "}
                diskline_cut2=${diskline##*" "}
                echo "/dev/$diskline_cut2"

        else
                alldisk=$(diskutil list)
                alldisk_cut1=${alldisk##*${maindrive_reduced}}
                alldisk_cut2=${alldisk_cut1#*"Logical Volume on "}
                alldisk_cut3=${alldisk_cut2%%" "*}
                echo /dev/$alldisk_cut3
fi
```

So, this should give you the EFI partition on the same hard drive as your root folder MacintoshHD.

EDIT 4 (Hopefully final version)

```
#!/bin/bash

maindrive=$(mount | grep -e " / ")
maindrive_exact=${maindrive%%" "*}
maindrive_reduced=${maindrive_exact##"/dev/"} 


function getdisknumber {
diskline=$(diskutil list | grep "[0-99]:" | grep $maindrive_reduced | grep EFI)
                diskline_cut1=${diskline##*"B "}
                diskline_cut2=${diskline##*" "}
                echo "/dev/$diskline_cut2"
}

if [ "$(diskutil list | grep Unlocked)" = "" ] 
    then 
        getdisknumber   
    else 
        alldisk=$(diskutil list)
        alldisk_cut=${alldisk#*${maindrive_reduced}}
        alldisk_cut=${alldisk_cut#*"Logical Volume on "}
        alldisk_cut=${alldisk_cut%%" "*}
        alldisk_cut=${alldisk_cut%s*}
        maindrive_reduced=$alldisk_cut
        getdisknumber
fi
```

And here's the explanation

```
Okay, as ask in the comment, the explanation what %%,%,##,# means. 
All those symbols cut out information of a string.
%%pattern cuts out the biggest pattern matching part to the right.
%pattern cuts out the smallest pattern matching part to the right.
##pattern cuts out the biggest pattern matching part to the left
#pattern cuts out the smallest pattern matching part to the left
```

The else part of the script now tries to find the right hard drive when confronted with a FileVault created encrypted Volume. The function then cuts this hard drive down to the disk information on this hard drive, looking for EFI as a keyword.

Here's a link about cutting strings in bash
[Cutting strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482123/extract-part-of-a-string-using-bash-cut-split)

EDIT 5:
Alright. Another iteration of this script. Very, very down to the basics.

```
#!/bin/bash

## Find the main hard drive

maindrive=$(mount | grep -e " / ")
maindrive=${maindrive#/dev/}
maindrive=${maindrive%%" "*}


## Checking for FileVault

if [ "" != "$(diskutil list /dev/disk1 | grep "Unlocked Encrypted")" ]
        then
                maindrive=$(diskutil list | grep "Logical Volume on")
                maindrive=${maindrive#*"Logical Volume on "}
                maindrive=${maindrive%s*}
fi


## Checking for EFI

EFI_DRIVE=$(diskutil list /dev/$maindrive | grep EFI)
EFI_DRIVE=${EFI_DRIVE##*" "}
echo "/dev/$EFI_DRIVE"
```

Just to be complete, that's my diskutil list:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         249.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *248.8 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

And this happens when I run the script:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:EFI_Script joe$ chmod +x EFI_Script
Joes-MacBook-Pro:EFI_Script joe$ ./EFI_Script
/dev/disk0s1
Joes-MacBook-Pro:EFI_Script joe$
```

I have thought about why it didn't work for you so far. So, basically, if that doesn't work either, I need two information from you. First, I will need to know your output for the ' mount ' command. Mine looks like this:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:EFI_Script joe$ mount
/dev/disk1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
```

As you see, it does give me the mountpoint '/' on 'disk1'. I simply assumed, if FileVault is turned off, it would give you your mountpoint on disk0. But maybe I am wrong and I have no system on which FileVault is turned off. So, should your mountpoint be also on disk1 while the EFI is on disk0, it should return empty or with only /dev/ since this is what I added manually. On the other hand, if I remember correctly, you had an EFI partition on disk1, too.

Anyway, the second thing I need would be that you run this script with the command 'bash -x script', so that it shows what it does while it is running. This way, we could see what goes wrong.

Anyway, I hope it just works and we don't have to go to these length. But if not, we have to figure out another way to find the main hard drive.

Anyway, test it.
Cheers!

Comment: Wow @TheCommoner282 you went to town on that one. 

`foo=$(df -h | grep -e ' /$'); loo=${foo%%" "*}; echo $loo` and ` produces the wrong drive ID,  `foo=$(mount | grep -e ' / '); foo=${foo%%" "*}; diskutil list | grep "[0-99]:" | grep ${foo##"/dev/"} | grep EFI; echo $foo` both produce /dev/disk0s2 rather than /dev/disk0s1. I'll test your longer script tomorrow.

Out of interest can you explain what, your use of %% and ## characters are doing as I can't find any documentation on them online. Ie in ${maindrive%%" "*}? I'm keen to learn.

Comment: I'll edit an explanation in. Also, I found a mistake in my script and will correct it

Comment: Oh my god, you're right. I just took a look at the second line. This is just dump. I 'echo $foo', which isn't changed in the second step. And the previous 'diskutil list' probably end up being blank. 

Well, bad start. But let's hope the fourth iteration works

Comment: Sorry it's taken a while for me to test your last suggestion @TheCommoner282 Unforuntately the script just outputs `/dev/`. Thanks for the explination on cutting in BASH. Really good info to know.

Comment: How strange. I guess, there must be some difference between our diskutil output I didn't take into account. I will rewrite the script and try to account. Also, I will try to add use your output that you posted for test purposes. I have an idea or two how to limit this to less information, means less cutting and therefore less errors or opportunity. You can expect this new version until tomorrow. I will do it tonight (based on Europe, GMT+1)

Comment: @juliushibert, I added another version. And I added some instruction on how to find the issue should it not work again. Anyway, just commenting here so you get a notification. I hope it works now. Cheers.